# Why error message "(" is missing whereas it isn't true?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I don't understand why `(` is missing?

```
if not exist ("C:\test") md "C:\test"
At line:1 char:3
+ if not exist ("C:\test") md "C:\test"
+   ~
Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingOpenParenthesisInIfStatement
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to run cmd.exe code inside powershell. In Powershell you would have to run it like this. `cmd.exe /C if not exist "C:\test" md "C:\test"`.

Comment: `if not exist "C:\test"` does not specifically check for the existence of a directory, and that is what you are specifically trying to ascertain! To check for a directory, you should instead try `if not exist "C:\test\*" md "C:\test"`.

Comment: Additionally, as it appears that you're running this in PowerShell, you could use its own methods, `If ( -Not ( Test-Path -Path 'C:\test' -PathType Container ) ) { New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path 'C:\test' }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on the helpful comments:

- You're trying to use `cmd.exe`'s syntax *directly from PowerShell*, which cannot work (given PowerShell's fundamentally different syntax) and causes the parsing error you saw.
- Use the PowerShell equivalent of your `cmd.exe` call, via [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item):

```sh
# Create directory C:\test or use a preexisting directory with that path
# (thanks to -Force). 
# A DirectoryInfo object describing the directory is returned, 
# which $null = ... discards.
$null = New-Item -Type Directory -Force C:\test
```

Comment: thanks I don't understand what you mean by which $null = ... discards.

Comment: @user310291, assigning a statement to `$null` discards the (success) output it produces. Without it, the output would print to the console (host) by default. Contrast `Get-Date` with `$null = Get-Date`.